# advanced jquery selection... first per attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, css-selectors

Okay, I'm not sure how to describe what i want to do concisely. So, take the following pseudo-html:

```
<input type=checkbox id=chk1 myatr=1 />
<input type=checkbox id=chk2 myatr=1 />
<input type=checkbox id=chk3 myatr=2 />
<input type=checkbox id=chk4 myatr=1 />
<input type=checkbox id=chk5 myatr=2 />
<input type=checkbox id=chk6 myatr=3 />
```

What i want to do is select all the checkboxes where they are the first occurrence of their respective value for "myatr". So i want to take something like:

```
$('input [type=checkbox]')
```

and extend it somehow to only get the items with ids chk1, chk3 and chk6, as they are the first instances of their values of myatr (1, 2 and 3 respectively).

Something like:

```
$('input [type=checkbox]').FirstForEach('myatr')
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zed's solution using objects (behaving like hashmaps) giving O(1) lookups as opposed to O(n) lookup of Array.

```
var attrs = {};
var prefix = "blah$$";
$("input [type=checkbox]").
  filter(
    function() {
      attr = this.attr("myatr");
      if (attrs[prefix + attr]) {
        return false;
      } else {
        attrs[prefix + attr] = true;
        return true;
      }
  )
```

A prefix is used to avoid collisions with built-in properties of object.

Comment: It would be interesting to measure how long attribute list it takes to actually have that o(1) of hashing go below the o(n) of array access.

Comment: Performance wise, it must be a really long array (1000+) elements to take notice. But objects are just right for this purpose. Also, look at the extra code you have to write implementing array_contains.

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution, but you can do something like this:

```
var attrs = new Array();

$("input [type=checkbox]").
  filter(
    function() {
      attr = this.attr("myatr");
      if ( array_contains(attrs, attr)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        array_insert(attrs, attr);
        return true;
      }
  ).
  ...
```

array_contains and array_insert should be implemented :)

Comment: You shouldn't use `new Array()` in JS, you should just use `[]`

Comment: You can just use attrs.push(attr) instead of array_insert(attrs, attr)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get that just calling jQuery build-in selectors. However you can easily get this in a few lines of code.

```
var ids = [];
$('input[type=checkbox]').filter(function (index) {
    var attr = $(this).attr('myattr');
    if (ids.indexOf(attr) !== -1) {
        ids[ids.length] = attr;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Untested but should work.

Note: IE doesn't have Array.indexOf method implemented but you can easily fix that with this code:

```
[].indexOf || (Array.prototype.indexOf = function(v){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (v === this[i]) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
});
```

Comment: An array is not really required. You can just use an object as a hashmap for faster results.